# SQL pattern doesn't work for basic statistics extraction inside a specific 5-95 quantiles

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'd like to extraction the mean, max, min and sd extraction inside 5-95 quantiles for the variables `B2`,
`B3`, `B4`, `B8`, `NDVI`, `SAVI`, `SIPI`, `SR`, `RGI`, `TVI`, `MSR`, `PRI`, `GNDVI`, `PSRI`, `GCI` aggregate by `AGE` and `ESPAC` variables inside a **CMPC** table:

My CMPC SQL table (`[PROJECT_ID].spectra_calibration.CMPC`) create inside BigQuery:

```
x   FLOAT   NULLABLE    
y   FLOAT   NULLABLE    
stand   STRING  NULLABLE    
date    STRING  NULLABLE    
B2  FLOAT   NULLABLE    
B3  FLOAT   NULLABLE    
B4  FLOAT   NULLABLE    
B8  FLOAT   NULLABLE    
NDVI    FLOAT   NULLABLE    
SAVI    FLOAT   NULLABLE    
SIPI    FLOAT   NULLABLE    
SR  FLOAT   NULLABLE    
RGI FLOAT   NULLABLE    
TVI INTEGER NULLABLE    
MSR FLOAT   NULLABLE    
PRI FLOAT   NULLABLE    
GNDVI   FLOAT   NULLABLE    
PSRI    FLOAT   NULLABLE    
GCI FLOAT   NULLABLE    
ID_PROJETO  INTEGER NULLABLE    
PROJETO STRING  NULLABLE    
CD_TALHAO   STRING  NULLABLE    
DATA_PLANT  STRING  NULLABLE    
ESPECIE STRING  NULLABLE    
ESPAC   STRING  NULLABLE    
AGE_1   FLOAT   NULLABLE    
AGE INTEGER NULLABLE
```

([Reference to a sample table in CSV](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/my_ds_CSV.csv))

I try to do the query for just one variable (`B2`) for the test and the desirable query inside the console by @Mabel A. courtesy was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AGE, ESPAC
,PERCENTILE_DISC(B2,0.05) OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC) AS P05_B2
,PERCENTILE_DISC(B2,0.95) OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC) AS P95_B2
,MIN(B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS MIN_B2
,AVG(B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS AVG_B2
,MAX(B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS MAX_B2
,stddev(B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS StDev_B2
FROM `[PROJECT_ID].spectra_calibration.CMPC`
ORDER BY AGE, ESPAC
```

My output is not the max, min, avg and sd just only inside 5 to 95 quantile interval, but the query results in all the table values:

```
Linha   AGE ESPAC   P05_B2  P95_B2  B2  
1   -2  4X1.85  100.0   149.0   134.0   
2   -2  4X1.85  100.0   149.0   106.0   
3   -2  4X1.85  100.0   149.0   129.0   
4   -2  4X1.85  100.0   149.0   121.5   
5   -2  4X1.85  100.0   149.0   152.0   
6   -2  4X1.85  100.0   149.0   157.0   
...
3518    13  3.5x2.14    53.0    167.0   62.0
```

The basic idea is a final result calculated (MAX, MIN, SD and AVG) with the `B2` values only with values >  `P05_B2` and < `P95_B2`. I'd like something with `B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2` conditions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AGE, ESPAC
,PERCENTILE_DISC(B2,0.05) OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC) AS P05_B2
,PERCENTILE_DISC(B2,0.95) OVER(PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC) AS P95_B2
,MIN(B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS MIN_B2
,AVG(B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS AVG_B2
,MAX(B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS MAX_B2
,stddev(B2 > P05_B2 & B2 < P95_B2) OVER (PARTITION BY AGE, ESPAC ORDER BY B2) AS StDev_B2
FROM `[PROJECT_ID].spectra_calibration.CMPC`
ORDER BY AGE, ESPAC
```

Please help with this query construction.

Comment: Can you provide an example complete data? You can do this by running SELECT * FROM  `[PROJECT_ID].spectra_calibration.CMPC`, then export it to a CSV file by clicking SAVE RESULTS on the Query results screen. You can limit the number of rows, just please make sure the data would have a variety of value for AGE and ESPAC. Also, can you provide an example output specially for P05_B2 and P95_B2?

Comment: Hi @Leprechault, please refrain from posting your project ID.

Comment: Hi @Leprechault, please delete project ID in your comment. Project IDs may be used to identify you so avoid including it on your questions in the future. I already removed project IDs in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WITHIN`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#within) modifier is used in an aggregate function and [`PERCENTILE_DISC`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#percentile_disc)  is a navigation function hence the error. Also, please take note that `WITHIN` is a legacy SQL syntax.

Found an article for conversion of [PERCENTILE_DISC function from Teradata to Bigquery](https://roboquery.com/app/eq-6489-Teradata-Bigquery).

**PERCENTILE_DISC function in Teradata:**

```
PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY X)
```

**PERCENTILE_DISC function equivalent in Bigquery:**

```
PERCENTILE_DISC(X,0.5) OVER()
```

Removed `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY B2)` in your script and it ran on my end without errors.

Comment: Thanks, @Mabel A., but unfortunately I don't have yet max, min, avg and sd just only inside 5 to 95 quantile interval, I have all the observations. I update the example too with your tips!!

Comment: Hi @Leprechault, the original question regarding the syntax error was already answered. As a common practice in StackOverflow, please post another question for concerns on the logic of your script. Please make sure to provide a valid sample data (columns for AGE, ESPAC & B2 with 10-20 rows of data would suffice) and a good visualization of the expected output.